# Equilibrium Constants for Diatomic Gases at High Temperatures

Tags: equilibrium, ions, reference-request, databases

I'm new here and I haven't taken chemistry beyond high school, so please forgive the ignorance. I am reading a book about hypersonic aerodynamics, and I am trying to connect some chemistry knowledge into my reading. I have four reactions listed in my book:

> $$
> \begin{align}
> \ce{O2 &-> 2 O} &\quad (\pu{2000K} < T < \pu{4000K})\\
> \ce{N2 &-> 2 N} &\quad (\pu{4000K} < T < \pu{9000K})\\
> \ce{N &-> N+ + e-} &\quad (T > \pu{9000K})\\
> \ce{O &-> O+ + e-} &\quad (T > \pu{9000K})
> \end{align}
> $$

Now, the book doesn't go into the chemistry here really at all. I know that some minor dissociation happens at cooler temperatures, and there will still be some diatomic oxygen/nitrogen at higher temperatures too. But I'm trying to answer for myself just how much is around at those temperatures, and how much they change in the ranges that they list. Assuming I remember correctly, I need the dissociation constants for this. However, I'm having trouble finding them.

NIST chemical reaction searching tool doesn't seem to have the information I'm looking for, and Wolfram|Alpha (which generally helps) is not understanding what I'm trying to tell it… so I'm at a loss. My chemical engineer family member mentioned I could find it in the *CRC Handbook of Chemistry and Physics*, but unfortunately we can't seem to find our copy. My chemistry-major friend in college knew that it was possible to get the numbers, but he couldn't quite remember where I should start.

Either way, I'm looking for the equilibrium coefficients of:

$$
\begin{array}{clr}
\hline
\# &\text{Reaction} & T/\pu{K} \\
\hline
1 & \ce{O2 -> 2O} & 2000 \\
2 & \ce{O2 -> 2O} & 4000 \\
3 & \ce{N2 -> 2N} & 4000 \\
4 & \ce{N2 -> 2N} & 9000 \\
5 & \ce{N -> N+ + e-} & 9000 \\
6 & \ce{N -> N+ + e-} & 11000 \\
7 & \ce{O -> O+ + e-} & 9000 \\
8 & \ce{O -> O+ + e-} & 11000 \\
\hline
\end{array}
$$

Can anyone either provide those values or help me find them somewhere? Even the reaction equilibrium constants that I can find are only listed at a single temperature (and never this high, because these temperatures are… uncommon).

Comment: related https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/124505/thermal-decomposition-of-steam-to-hydrogen-and-oxygen-at-what-temperature-is-ha https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/133766/is-silicon-dioxide-decomposition-possible

Comment: I would suggest that you post this in physics. Astrophysicists would be interested in this type of data. I do vaguely recall Saha equation in atomic spectroscopy related to ionization equilibrium in at very high temperatures. You will not find this data in ordinary chemistry or web. Not everything is out there on the web.

Comment: @M.Farooq I will take a look in the Physics Stack Exchange -- thanks for the tip. I'll leave it here too, though, in case someone has more information (even on just to calculate it at a nonstandard temperature). I will look into the Saha Equation, I appreciate the suggestion. Glad that I wasn't just ignorant at not being able to find it!

Comment: And thank you, @andselisk, for reformatting. I couldn't figure out how to use LaTeX commands after ten minutes of trying, so I just gave up.

Comment: @Publius No prob. I would, however, strongly encourage you to get to know MathJax and LaTeX common macros if you plan to do a substantial amount of scientific writing. Feel free visit [this page](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/notation), [this page](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/443/) and [this one](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/86/) on how to format your future posts better with MathJax and Markdown. For LaTeX there is [TeX.SE](https://tex.stackexchange.com/). And remember that MathJax ≠ LaTeX, they only share some command names.

Comment: @andselisk oh, I do know LaTeX! That's what I typeset my homework in actually. For some reason, it wasn't liking my LaTeX code when I put it into the window; does it compile when I hit "post?" Or is there a button to compile LaTeX code that I just missed? I was able to typeset LaTeX code just fine when I posted on the TeX SE, but for some reason it wasn't having it here.

Comment: @Publius I'm really glad you are using LaTeX. Unfortunately, [MathJax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MathJax) is not a full-featured LaTeX distro and works entirely differently. It's just a JavaScript library which happens to share some macros names with LaTeX, so don't expect full compatibility and packages support. Packages must be rewritten from the ground up to be used with MathJax, this, for example, happened with `mhchem`, but there is no `siunitx` in MathJax.

Comment: @Publius So, no, when you hit "Post" button nothing is going to change as MathJax renders the result nearly in the real time (unless there are hundreds of formulas).

Comment: @andselisk Gotcha, I understand now I think. Thank you so much for the tip!